# Github GraphQL API: non-existent repositories showing up in response

Tags: node.js, api, github, graphql, github-api

I have a little web app called RepoSweeper (https://reposweeper.com/) which I built after my coding bootcamp. It's purpose is to bulk delete unused repos from GitHub.

A while back GitHub changed the way you access repos via the API and Private repos stopped showing up in the results. So I had a freelancer modify the code to use GraphQL to make the request.

Now all the repos show up (hooray!) but there are a huge number of repos that don't exist in my Repositories on Github. My first thought was that they are archived, but the isArchived flag is false in the response data.

This is the GraphQL query:

```
export const REPO_INFO_QUERY = gql`


query ($ghLogin: String!, $after: String) {
    user(login: $ghLogin) {
      id
      name
      login
      avatarUrl
      bioHTML
      repositories(first: 100, after: $after, ownerAffiliations: [OWNER, ORGANIZATION_MEMBER, COLLABORATOR]) {
        totalCount
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
          __typename
        }
        nodes {
          id
          viewerCanAdminister
          name
          description
          isFork
          isPrivate
          isArchived
          updatedAt
          createdAt
          url
          parent {
            nameWithOwner
            url
            __typename
          }
          owner {
            login
            url
            __typename
          }
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
  }
`;
```

This is the request:

```
  const endpoint = `https://api.github.com/graphql`

  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })

  const variables = {ghLogin: user, archived: true, isArchived: true}

  return graphQLClient.request(REPO_INFO_QUERY, variables).then(data => {
    debugger
    return data
  })
    .catch(err => {
      Popup.alert('Error: '+ err)
      return false
    }
  )
```

And this is what the non-existent repo data looks like:

[image]

Love to hear what you guys think. Thank you!

Comment: This is a guess, but [looking at the API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos), the repository can also be `disabled` (another option is a template repository, which may also look different in the API). [GitHub Blog -  Disabling projects](https://github.blog/2017-03-24-disabling-projects/), related question: [How to tell if a repo is active or disabled using the GitHub API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23744959/7586)